# How to perform calculation in a specific column with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am looking for a clean solution to perform calculation from a single column with a few conditions and insert it in the same table. My existing solution is to use a while loop with many variable declarations, writing simple query to store value, perform calculation and finally insert it as a new row to the table. However it looks messy and complicated. I am wondering if there is a better solution to it?

Original Table

```
Week | Indicator | Value
  1        A         2
  1        B         3

  1        D         10
  1        E         5 

  1        X         12
  1        Y         6

  2        A         4
  2        B         5

  2        D         7
  2        E         3 

  2        X         4
  2        Y         2
 ...
 53
```

Updated Table

```
Week | Indicator | Value
  1        A         2
  1        B         3
  1        C         5

  1        D         10
  1        E         5
  1        F         5

  1        X         12
  1        Y         6
  1        Z         2

  2        A         4
  2        B         5
  2        C         9

  2        D         7
  2        E         3 
  2        F         4

  2        X         4
  2        Y         2
  2        Z         2
```

In this example in the **updated table**, every 3rd row involves different calculation for the same week such that the 3rd row is an addition, 6th row is a subtraction and the 9th row is a division.

The calculation does not restrict to only addition and could include other forms of calculation formulas. I am just using addition as a simple illustration.

Here is an example of my SQL solution:

```
DECLARE @total_rows int;
SET @total_rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM original_table);

DECLARE @wk varchar(5);
DECLARE @indicator1 char(1);
DECLARE @indicator2 char(1);
SET @indicator1 = 'A';
SET @indicator2 = 'B';

DECLARE @a_value int;
DECLARE @b_value int;
DECLARE @cal_value int;

DECLARE @iteration int
SET @iteration = 1

WHILE @iteration <= @total_rows
BEGIN

IF @iteration <= 53
    SET @wk = concat('W',@iteration)

SET  @a_value = (SELECT value 
FROM original_table
WHERE indicator = @indicator1 and week = @wk);

SET  @b_value = (SELECT value
FROM original_table
WHERE indicator = @indicator2 and week = @wk);

SET @cal_value =  (@a_value/ NULLIF(@b_value,0)) *1000000;
.... 

SET @iteration = @iteration + 1    
END
```

Not going to post the entire SQL script as it is quite lengthy but I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: *"3rd row is an addition, 6th row is a subtraction and the 9th row is a division."* What about the 12th, the 15th, the 30th??? Where is the indicator for what the arithmetic that needs to be applied is?

Comment: I would just need to know how I could apply different arithmetic based on the the different values in the indicator column within the same week. Given the 3rd, 6th and 9th rows, I believe it should suffice to replicate it for the nth no. of rows.

Comment: And yet you *still* haven't explained where that arithmetic operator comes from. Without that, you can't do what you;'re after as SQL Server doesn't have the ability to read your mind, and neither do we. Help us help you.

Comment: The arithmetic is defined by users but for simplicity sake, I am asking how it can be solve with (+,-,/,*)

Answer (score 0):

Is this not as simple as `INSERT` and `SUM`..?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable ([Week],Indicator,[Value])
SELECT YT.[Week],
       'C' AS Indicator,
       SUM(YT.[Value]) AS [Value]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
GROUP BY YT.[Week];
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d44f0b142df038584db7cdfdce89f33)

Comment: Hi Laru, this solution will work if I plan to use the same formula for all indicators but I need to use certain indicators for different formulas.

Comment: Then give us those examples, @JamesChew . You gave us 2 examples and this works for those 2 examples. This suggests your examples are incomplete.

Comment: Also, there is an `n` in my alias. :)

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete examples. I have updated it! @larnu

Comment: But you haven't explain how you know what calculation to apply, @JamesChew .

Comment: I have edited it to make it a bit clearer. Do let me know if its still unclear-